# Pandas json_normalize returns KeyError

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset from a json file like this format:

```
data = {'data': {'content': [{'gender': 'Female',
    'id': 'covid-1004200003256',
    'state_code': '3272',
    'district_code': '3272040',
    'subdistrict_code': '3272040004',
    'latitude': -6.906,
    'longitude': 106.923,
    'state_name': 'KOTA SUKABUMI',
    'district_name': 'Gunungpuyuh',
    'subdistrict_name': 'Karamat',
    'stage': 'Isolated',
    'status': 'SUSPECT'},
   {'gender': 'Female',
    'id': 'covid-1004200003255',
    'state_code': '3272',
    'district_code': '3272040',
    'subdistrict_code': '3272040004',
    'latitude': -6.906,
    'longitude': 106.923,
    'state_name': 'KOTA SUKABUMI',
    'district_name': 'Gunungpuyuh',
    'subdistrict_name': 'Karamat',
    'stage': 'Isolated',
    'status': 'SUSPECT',
    }]}}
```

So I want to make a dataframe using `json_normalize`

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'content')
df.head(10)
```

But it returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-4d8ad8c8743a> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'content')
      2 df.head(10)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in _json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep, max_level)
    334                 records.extend(recs)
    335 
--> 336     _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
    337 
    338     result = DataFrame(records)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in _recursive_extract(data, path, seen_meta, level)
    307         else:
    308             for obj in data:
--> 309                 recs = _pull_records(obj, path[0])
    310                 recs = [
    311                     nested_to_record(r, sep=sep, max_level=max_level)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in _pull_records(js, spec)
    246         if has non iterable value.
    247         """
--> 248         result = _pull_field(js, spec)
    249 
    250         # GH 31507 GH 30145, GH 26284 if result is not list, raise TypeError if not

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in _pull_field(js, spec)
    237                 result = result[field]
    238         else:
--> 239             result = result[spec]
    240         return result
    241 

KeyError: 'content'
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is failing because you are trying to pass 2nd level of nested key(`content`). You can only pass `first` level of nested keys.

So, you need to pass `data['data']`, like below:

```
In [934]: df = pd.json_normalize(data['data'], 'content')

In [934]: df
Out[934]: 
   gender                   id state_code district_code subdistrict_code  latitude  longitude     state_name district_name subdistrict_name     stage   status
0  Female  covid-1004200003256       3272       3272040       3272040004    -6.906    106.923  KOTA SUKABUMI   Gunungpuyuh          Karamat  Isolated  SUSPECT
1  Female  covid-1004200003255       3272       3272040       3272040004    -6.906    106.923  KOTA SUKABUMI   Gunungpuyuh          Karamat  Isolated  SUSPECT
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the array of records in directly:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['data']['content'])
```