# Convert JSON data to pandas df - python

Tags: python, json, json-normalize

I know there is a few questions on SO regarding the conversion of JSON file to a pandas df but nothing is working. Specifically, the JSON requests the current days information. I'm trying to return the tabular structure that corresponds with `Data` but I'm only getting the first `dict` object.

I'll list the current attempts and the resulting outputs below.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

get_session_url = "https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/"
get_data_url = "https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/services/wxdata.svc/GetDataX"

get_data_query = {
    "token": None,
    "reportCode": "MSQ-WEB-0001",
    "dataSource": None,
    "filterName": "Today",
    "parameters": [{
            "__type": "ParameterValueDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO",
            "sName": "DOMAIN_ID",
            "iValueType": 0,
            "aoValues": [{"Value": -1}],
                  }],
    "metaVersion": 0,
}

sess = requests.session()

sess.get(get_session_url).raise_for_status()

my_dict = sess.post(get_data_url, json = get_data_query).json()

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'d': {'__type': 'DataSetDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'BuildVersion': '7.0.0.12590', 'ReportCode': 'MSQ-WEB-0001', 'Tables': [{'__type': 'DataTableDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'BuildVersion': '7.0.0.12590', 'AsOfDate': '14:36 on Jan 19', 'Data': [[132378, 334489, 'EXT', 'NANA Z', 'BULK CARRIER', 229.2, 'LBH Australia Pty Ltd (Mackay)', '/Date(1642600800000+1000)/', '/Date(1642600800000+1000)/', 'SEA for HPS', 'Anch for HPS & DBCT', 'PLAN', 'Keelung (Chilung)', 'Kwangyang', None, 633086, 705], [132112, 333984, 'DEP', 'KRITI WARRIOR', 'BULK CARRIER', 234.98, 'Wilhelmsen Ships Service (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642600800000+1000)/', '/Date(1642608900000+1000)/', 'Fishermans Landing 1', 'SEA', 'CONF', 'Amrun', 'Amrun', '2201', 632395, 725], [132232, 334208, 'EXT', 'BLUE GRASS MARINER', 'TANKER', 183.06, 'Gulf Agency Company (Mackay)', '/Date(1642600860000+1000)/', '/Date(1642600860000+1000)/', 'SEA M', 'Anch for MKY', 'PLAN', 'Gladstone', 'Singapore', None, 633566, 705], [132654, 335076, 'EXT', 'SERIFOS WARRIOR', 'BULK CARRIER', 234.98, 'Wilhelmsen Ships Service (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642606200000+1000)/', '/Date(1642609800000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Fairway Buoy Anchorage', 'PLAN', 'Amrun', 'Amrun', '2201', 632055, 705], [132030, 333847, 'ARR', 'MH GREEN', 'CONTAINER SHIP', 199.98, 'Inchcape Shipping Services (Queensland)', '/Date(1642610700000+1000)/', '/Date(1642623300000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Fisherman Island No 8', 'SCHD', 'Yantian', 'Botany Bay', '11S/11N', 633005, 710], [131681, 333193, 'ARR', 'KM NAGOYA', 'BULK CARRIER', 234.98, 'Gulf Agency Company (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642611600000+1000)/', '/Date(1642618800000+1000)/', 'Fairway Buoy Anchorage', 'Clinton Coal 2', 'CONF', 'Fangcheng', 'Singapore', None, 633504, 725], [132781, 335341, 'ARR', 'MORNING CLARA', 'VEHICLES CARRIER', 199.9, 'Wilhelmsen Ships Service (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642611600000+1000)/', '/Date(1642626000000+1000)/', 'Drift Point Cartwright', 'Fisherman Island No 1', 'SCHD', 'Tianjin', 'Port Kembla', '2251', 633093, 710], [131971, 333736, 'DEP', 'MAPLE FORTITUDE', 'BULK CARRIER', 179.9, 'Inchcape Shipping Services (Queensland)', '/Date(1642615200000+1000)/', '/Date(1642621500000+1000)/', 'Townsville 09', 'SEA', 'SCHD', 'Lanshan', 'Auckland', '2101', 633738, 710], [131629, 333076, 'DEP', 'JP CORAL', 'BULK CARRIER', 228.0, 'Sturrock Grindrod Maritime (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642617000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642625100000+1000)/', 'Clinton Coal 2', 'SEA', 'CONF', 'Matsushima - Nagasaki', 'Matsuura - Nagasaki', '146', 631305, 725], [130504, 331071, 'ARR', 'KENNADI', 'BULK CARRIER', 199.9, 'LBH Australia Pty Ltd (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642617000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642626000000+1000)/', 'East Anchorage 9', 'Clinton Coal 4', 'CONF', 'Kwangyang', 'Kendari - Sulawesi', '37', 633759, 725], [131497, 332926, 'ARR', 'STAR VIRGINIA', 'BULK CARRIER', 229.0, 'Inchcape Shipping Services (Queensland)', '/Date(1642617900000+1000)/', '/Date(1642633200000+1000)/', 'Point Cartwright Anchorage', 'Fisherman Island Coal Berth', 'SCHD', 'Kitakyushu', 'Fukuyama - Hiroshima', '2', 632115, 710], [132459, 334657, 'ARR', 'NORD ANNAPOLIS', 'BULK CARRIER', 179.9, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642617900000+1000)/', '/Date(1642625100000+1000)/', 'East Anchorage 11', 'Auckland Point 2', 'CONF', 'Portland', 'Chittagong', '26', 633752, 725], [132563, 334863, 'DEP', 'POSITIVE LEADER', 'VEHICLES CARRIER', 180.0, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642622400000+1000)/', '/Date(1642635000000+1000)/', 'Fisherman Island No 1', 'SEA', 'SCHD', 'Townsville', 'Port Kembla', '090', 632525, 710], [132221, 334613, 'ARR', 'DANCEWOOD SW', 'BULK CARRIER', 170.7, 'Inchcape Shipping Services (Queensland)', '/Date(1642622400000+1000)/', '/Date(1642640400000+1000)/', 'Point Cartwright Anchorage', 'Pinkenba No 1', 'SCHD', 'Guam', 'Shibushi', '202201', 632332, 710], [132357, 334450, 'EXT', 'DOUBLE FANTASY', 'BULK CARRIER', 234.98, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Townsville & Abbot Point)', '/Date(1642622400000+1000)/', '/Date(1642622400000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Abbot Point Anchorage', 'SCHD', 'Chiba', None, None, 631611, 710], [132431, 334598, 'DEP', 'INDUS PROSPERITY', 'BULK CARRIER', 229.2, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Townsville & Abbot Point)', '/Date(1642624200000+1000)/', '/Date(1642624200000+1000)/', 'Abott Point 2', 'SEA', 'SCHD', 'Chiba', 'Dung Quat', None, 627891, 710], [132465, 334672, 'DEP', 'KOTA LUMAYAN', 'CONTAINER SHIP', 260.502, 'Gulf Agency Company (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642626000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642639500000+1000)/', 'Fisherman Island No. 9', 'SEA', 'PLAN', 'Singapore', 'Sydney', '0147', 632026, 705], [132356, 334446, 'ARR', 'TRITON', 'BULK CARRIER', 225.0, 'Sturrock Grindrod Maritime (Mackay)', '/Date(1642626000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642632000000+1000)/', 'North Anchorage 22', 'HPS Berth 2', 'SCHD', 'Gunsan (ex Kunsan)', 'Singapore', '012022', 633638, 710], [132430, 334595, 'ARR', 'GOLDEN YOSA', 'TANKER', 144.03, 'Sturrock Grindrod Maritime (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642626000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642644000000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Viva Energy', 'SCHD', 'Geelong', 'Townsville', '74(C1)', 628015, 710], [132631, 335048, 'DEP', 'MONDIAL SUN', 'BULK CARRIER', 229.0, 'Ben Line Agencies', '/Date(1642626000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642629600000+1000)/', 'Abbot Point 1', 'SEA', 'SCHD', 'Bahudopi', 'India', '018', 633700, 710], [132451, 334640, 'EXT', 'GOLDEN HACHI', 'TANKER', 126.8, 'Sturrock Grindrod Maritime (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642626000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642626000000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Point Cartwright Anchorage', 'PLAN', 'Singapore', 'Botany Bay', '10', 632483, 705], [132442, 334622, 'DEP', 'FOREVER SW', 'BULK CARRIER', 189.99, 'Gulf Agency Company (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642626000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642643100000+1000)/', 'Fisherman Island Coal Berth', 'SEA', 'SCHD', 'Toledo/Cebu', 'Kushiro', '2A', 569051, 710], [132572, 334905, 'ARR', 'GREEK FRIENDSHIP', 'BULK CARRIER', 228.9, 'LBH Australia Pty Ltd (Mackay)', '/Date(1642627800000+1000)/', '/Date(1642627800000+1000)/', 'Abbot Point Anchorage 11', 'Abott Point 2', 'SCHD', 'Tianjin', 'Singapore', None, 633660, 710], [132262, 334259, 'DEP', 'ASTREA', 'BULK CARRIER', 228.99, 'Wave Shipping Pty Ltd', '/Date(1642627800000+1000)/', '/Date(1642627860000+1000)/', 'HPS Berth 1', 'SEA Paddock Departure', 'PLAN', 'Lianyungang', 'Singapore', '1', 633595, 705], [132510, 334762, 'DEP', 'BRILLIANT ADVANCE', 'BULK CARRIER', 228.99, 'Wilhelmsen Ships Service (Weipa)', '/Date(1642629600000+1000)/', '/Date(1642633200000+1000)/', 'Chith Export Facility', 'SEA', 'CONF', 'Laizhou', 'Gladstone', None, 631808, 725], [132170, 334112, 'ARR', 'LOWLANDS CRIMSON', 'BULK CARRIER', 234.96, 'Wilhelmsen Ships Service (Weipa)', '/Date(1642629600000+1000)/', '/Date(1642636800000+1000)/', 'Anchorage ^D', 'Chith Export Facility', 'CONF', 'Gladstone', 'China', None, 630787, 725], [132433, 334601, 'DEP', 'PT NORFOLK', 'GENERAL CARGO BARGE', 70.15, 'Pacific Tug (Aust) PTY LTD', '/Date(1642631400000+1000)/', '/Date(1642635000000+1000)/', 'Marina', 'Bundaberg Anchorage', 'CONF', None, None, None, 624749, 725], [132428, 334591, 'REM', 'PT KYTHIRA', 'TUG', 26.0, 'Pacific Tug (Aust) PTY LTD', '/Date(1642631400000+1000)/', '/Date(1642635000000+1000)/', 'Marina', 'Bundaberg Anchorage', 'CONF', None, 'Brisbane', None, 570086, 725], [131637, 333097, 'ARR', 'BALZANI', 'TANKER', 228.418, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642632300000+1000)/', '/Date(1642642200000+1000)/', 'North Anchorage 7', 'Fishermans Landing 2', 'CONF', 'Yeosu (ex Yosu)', 'Port Kembla', '32106', 632359, 725], [132699, 335167, 'EXT', 'FEDERAL IMABARI', 'BULK CARRIER', 199.98, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642633200000+1000)/', '/Date(1642633200000+1000)/', 'Skardon River Anchorage', 'SEA', 'CONF', None, None, None, 624678, 725], [132451, 335328, 'ARR', 'GOLDEN HACHI', 'TANKER', 126.8, 'Sturrock Grindrod Maritime (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642635000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642651200000+1000)/', 'Point Cartwright Anchorage', 'Ampol Lytton Products', 'PLAN', 'Singapore', 'Botany Bay', '10', 632483, 705], [131897, 333604, 'DEP', 'PROTEUS', 'TANKER', 183.06, 'Gulf Agency Company (Mackay)', '/Date(1642635000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642635060000+1000)/', 'Mackay Berth 1', 'SEA MKY', 'SCHD', 'Gladstone', 'Townsville', None, 633592, 710], [132059, 333886, 'ARR', 'RTM WAKMATHA', 'BULK CARRIER', 236.0, 'Wilhelmsen Ships Service (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642635000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642644900000+1000)/', 'Fairway Buoy Anchorage', 'Fishermans Landing 1', 'CONF', 'Gove', 'Amrun', None, 633057, 725], [132024, 333833, 'ARR', 'MARIA PRINCESS', 'TANKER', 228.59, 'Gulf Agency Company (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642635000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642654800000+1000)/', 'Point Cartwright Anchorage', 'Fishermans Island Tanker Terminal', 'SCHD', 'Seria Brunei', None, None, 633606, 710], [132504, 334740, 'EXT', 'MAIRAKI', 'BULK CARRIER', 291.9, 'LBH Australia Pty Ltd (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642636800000+1000)/', '/Date(1642636800000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Drift Gladstone', 'PLAN', 'Tianjin', None, '43', 633705, 705], [132029, 333846, 'DEP', 'MANTA NILGUN', 'GENERAL CARGO', 179.99, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642637700000+1000)/', '/Date(1642644000000+1000)/', 'South Trees East', 'SEA', 'CONF', 'Port Moresby', 'Nakhodka', '202201', 632946, 725], [132001, 333781, 'ARR', 'NSU KEYSTONE', 'BULK CARRIER', 299.94, 'Inchcape Shipping Services (Queensland)', '/Date(1642638600000+1000)/', '/Date(1642644000000+1000)/', 'North Anchorage 19', 'DBCT Berth 1', 'SCHD', 'Yeosu (ex Yosu)', 'Kimitsu', '57', 633532, 710], [131382, 332650, 'EXT', 'AQUADIVA', 'BULK CARRIER', 292.0, 'Gulf Agency Company (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642639500000+1000)/', '/Date(1642643100000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Fairway Buoy Anchorage', 'PLAN', 'Bayuquan', 'Abbot Point', None, 633453, 705], [132417, 334562, 'DEP', 'KMARIN KENAI', 'BULK CARRIER', 229.0, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Mackay)', '/Date(1642640400000+1000)/', '/Date(1642644000000+1000)/', 'DBCT Berth 1', 'SEA Paddock Departure', 'SCHD', 'Yeosu (ex Yosu)', 'Sepetiba', None, 633645, 710], [132708, 335184, 'ARR', 'MSC ELA', 'CONTAINER SHIP', 294.06, 'Mediterranean Shipping Company', '/Date(1642641300000+1000)/', '/Date(1642654800000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Fisherman Island No. 9', 'SCHD', 'Sydney', 'Shanghai', 'SE151R', 633718, 710], [132611, 335017, 'DEP', 'SSB 1803', 'BARGE CARRIER', 52.7, 'Sea Swift Pty Ltd', '/Date(1642644000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642647600000+1000)/', 'Hammond Island', 'SEA', 'CONF', None, None, None, 586569, 725], [132429, 334592, 'EXT', 'LEONORA VICTORY', 'TANKER', 183.2, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642644000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642644000000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Fairway Buoy Anchorage', 'PLAN', 'Balboa', 'Unknown Port', '32', 633737, 705], [132601, 335000, 'DEP', 'NORMAN RIVER', 'TUG', 24.45, 'Sea Swift Pty Ltd', '/Date(1642644000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642647600000+1000)/', 'Hammond Island', 'SEA', 'CONF', 'Cape Flattery', 'Cairns', None, 633691, 725], [132079, 335477, 'EXT', 'DEE4 LARCH', 'TANKER', 183.06, 'Inchcape Shipping Services (Queensland)', '/Date(1642646040000+1000)/', '/Date(1642646040000+1000)/', 'East Anchorage 6', 'SEA', 'PLAN', 'Etajima', 'Unknown Port', '1', 632184, 705], [132470, 334682, 'ARR', 'CASTILLO DE SANTISTEBAN', 'LIQUEFIED GAS TANKER', 299.9, 'Gulf Agency Company (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642646700000+1000)/', '/Date(1642658400000+1000)/', 'LNG Anchorage 2', 'Queensland Curtis LNG', 'CONF', 'Taiwan', 'Ningbo', None, 632133, 725], [132434, 334603, 'REM', 'PT NORFOLK', 'GENERAL CARGO BARGE', 70.15, 'Pacific Tug (Aust) PTY LTD', '/Date(1642647600000+1000)/', '/Date(1642662000000+1000)/', 'Shark Spit Anchorage', 'Queensport', 'SCHD', None, None, None, 624749, 710], [132538, 334816, 'EXT', 'WINCANTON', 'LIQUEFIED GAS TANKER', 119.95, 'Inchcape Shipping Services (Queensland)', '/Date(1642647600000+1000)/', '/Date(1642647600000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Fairway Buoy Anchorage', 'PLAN', 'Newcastle', 'Newcastle', '264', 632386, 705], [132432, 334600, 'REM', 'PT KYTHIRA', 'TUG', 26.0, 'Pacific Tug (Aust) PTY LTD', '/Date(1642647600000+1000)/', '/Date(1642662000000+1000)/', 'Shark Spit Anchorage', 'Queensport', 'SCHD', 'Bundaberg', None, None, 570086, 710], [131727, 333300, 'ARR', 'SEMIRAMIS', 'BULK CARRIER', 228.9, 'Sturrock Grindrod Maritime (Mackay)', '/Date(1642647660000+1000)/', '/Date(1642653060000+1000)/', 'South Anchorage 09', 'HPS Berth 1', 'PLAN', 'Jingtang (Tangshan)', 'Singapore', 'TP0264', 633516, 705], [132130, 335179, 'ARR', 'CHORUS', 'BULK CARRIER', 228.99, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Mackay)', '/Date(1642649400000+1000)/', None, 'North Anchorage 06', 'DBCT Berth 3', 'SCHD', 'Busan', 'Kakogawa', '80', 633558, 710], [132439, 334614, 'EXT', 'SM TIGER', 'BULK CARRIER', 292.0, 'LBH Australia Pty Ltd (Mackay)', '/Date(1642649400000+1000)/', '/Date(1642649400000+1000)/', 'SEA for HPS', 'Anch for HPS & DBCT', 'PLAN', 'Kwangyang', 'Pohang', '50', 633640, 705], [132795, 335381, 'ARR', 'ALBATROSS BAY', 'LANDING CRAFT', 64.0, 'Sea Swift Pty Ltd', '/Date(1642651200000+1000)/', '/Date(1642654800000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Horn Island', 'CONF', 'Cairns', 'Seisia', 'AB 2203', 633274, 725], [132433, 335356, 'ARR', 'PT NORFOLK', 'GENERAL CARGO BARGE', 70.15, 'Pacific Tug (Aust) PTY LTD', '/Date(1642651200000+1000)/', '/Date(1642654800000+1000)/', 'Bundaberg Anchorage', 'Marina', 'CONF', None, None, None, 624749, 725], [132428, 335355, 'REM', 'PT KYTHIRA', 'TUG', 26.0, 'Pacific Tug (Aust) PTY LTD', '/Date(1642651200000+1000)/', '/Date(1642654800000+1000)/', 'Bundaberg Anchorage', 'Marina', 'CONF', None, 'Brisbane', None, 570086, 725], [132295, 334319, 'DEP', 'HOEGH KOBE', 'VEHICLES CARRIER', 199.1, 'Seaway Agencies Pty Ltd', '/Date(1642654800000+1000)/', '/Date(1642669200000+1000)/', 'Wagners', 'SEA', 'SCHD', 'Auckland', 'Port Kembla', '68', 631289, 710], [132291, 334306, 'ARR', 'LOCH MAREE', 'BULK CARRIER', 176.83, 'Wave Shipping Pty Ltd', '/Date(1642655700000+1000)/', '/Date(1642672800000+1000)/', 'Point Cartwright Anchorage', 'Fisherman Island General Purpose Berth', 'SCHD', 'Fujairah', 'Lae', '9', 633744, 710], [132232, 334209, 'ARR', 'BLUE GRASS MARINER', 'TANKER', 183.06, 'Gulf Agency Company (Mackay)', '/Date(1642657200000+1000)/', '/Date(1642657260000+1000)/', 'Anch for MKY', 'Mackay Berth 1', 'SCHD', 'Gladstone', 'Singapore', None, 633566, 710], [132538, 334817, 'ARR', 'WINCANTON', 'LIQUEFIED GAS TANKER', 119.95, 'Inchcape Shipping Services (Queensland)', '/Date(1642657500000+1000)/', '/Date(1642668300000+1000)/', 'Fairway Buoy Anchorage', 'Fishermans Landing 5', 'CONF', 'Newcastle', 'Newcastle', '264', 632386, 725], [132473, 334686, 'EXT', 'GREAT CHEER', 'BULK CARRIER', 229.2, 'LBH Australia Pty Ltd (Mackay)', '/Date(1642658400000+1000)/', '/Date(1642658400000+1000)/', 'SEA for HPS', 'Anch for HPS & DBCT', 'PLAN', 'Kakogawa', 'Indonesia', '2201VC', 633677, 705], [132513, 334770, 'DEP', 'KAI YANG STAR', 'BULK CARRIER', 234.98, 'Wilhelmsen Ships Service (Weipa)', '/Date(1642659300000+1000)/', '/Date(1642666500000+1000)/', 'Lorim West', 'SEA', 'CONF', 'Dongjiakou', 'Qingdao', None, 633694, 725], [132575, 335351, 'EXT', 'IPSEA COLOSSUS', 'BULK CARRIER', 197.0, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Townsville & Abbot Point)', '/Date(1642662000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642662000000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Abbot Point Anchorage', 'SCHD', 'Chittagong', None, None, 625240, 710], [132285, 334295, 'DEP', 'FW EXCURSIONIST', 'BULK CARRIER', 179.9, 'Wave Shipping Pty Ltd', '/Date(1642662000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642679100000+1000)/', 'Fisherman Island General Purpose Berth', 'SEA', 'SCHD', 'Busan', 'New Plymouth', '24', 633667, 710], [132364, 334463, 'EXT', 'JUPITER', 'BULK CARRIER', 225.0, 'LBH Australia Pty Ltd (Mackay)', '/Date(1642663800000+1000)/', '/Date(1642663800000+1000)/', 'SEA for DBCT', 'Anch for HPS & DBCT', 'PLAN', 'Rizhao', 'Singapore', '17', 633643, 705], [132781, 335342, 'DEP', 'MORNING CLARA', 'VEHICLES CARRIER', 199.9, 'Wilhelmsen Ships Service (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642665600000+1000)/', '/Date(1642680000000+1000)/', 'Fisherman Island No 1', 'SEA', 'SCHD', 'Tianjin', 'Port Kembla', '2251', 633093, 710], [131704, 333251, 'DEP', 'TANGGUH JAYA', 'LIQUEFIED GAS TANKER', 285.1, 'Wilhelmsen Ships Service (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642666500000+1000)/', '/Date(1642676400000+1000)/', 'Santos GLNG', 'SEA', 'CONF', 'Mexico', 'Incheon', None, 633458, 725], [130826, 331647, 'ARR', 'DL DAHLIA', 'BULK CARRIER', 229.0, 'Monson Agencies Australia (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642668300000+1000)/', '/Date(1642677300000+1000)/', 'Fairway Buoy Anchorage', 'Clinton Coal 1', 'CONF', 'Yeongheung', 'Tanjung Bin', '2712', 633296, 725], [132582, 334934, 'DEP', 'CORAL GEOGRAPHER', 'PASSENGER', 94.5, 'Coral Expeditions', '/Date(1642669200000+1000)/', '/Date(1642672800000+1000)/', 'C123', 'SEA', 'CONF', 'Cairns', 'Cairns', None, 633369, 725], [130422, 330911, 'DEP', 'NSU QUEST', 'BULK CARRIER', 299.94, 'Inchcape Shipping Services (Queensland)', '/Date(1642673700000+1000)/', '/Date(1642682700000+1000)/', 'Clinton Coal 3', 'SEA', 'CONF', 'Hay Point', 'Japan', '45', 632982, 725], [132795, 335383, 'REM', 'ALBATROSS BAY', 'LANDING CRAFT', 64.0, 'Sea Swift Pty Ltd', '/Date(1642674600000+1000)/', '/Date(1642676400000+1000)/', 'Horn Island', 'Main Jetty', 'CONF', 'Cairns', 'Seisia', 'AB 2203', 633274, 725], [132759, 335288, 'EXT', 'CMB PAUILLAC', 'BULK CARRIER', 235.0, 'Wilhelmsen Ships Service (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642675500000+1000)/', '/Date(1642679100000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Fairway Buoy Anchorage', 'PLAN', 'Gove', 'Weipa', None, 633160, 705], [132430, 334596, 'DEP', 'GOLDEN YOSA', 'TANKER', 144.03, 'Sturrock Grindrod Maritime (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642676400000+1000)/', '/Date(1642692600000+1000)/', 'Viva Energy', 'SEA', 'SCHD', 'Geelong', 'Townsville', '74(C1)', 628015, 710], [132456, 334647, 'EXT', 'MISSY ENTERPRISE', 'GENERAL CARGO', 181.16, 'Wave Shipping Pty Ltd', '/Date(1642676400000+1000)/', '/Date(1642676460000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Bundaberg Anchorage', 'PLAN', 'Singapore', 'Japan', '2', 631532, 705], [132389, 335619, 'EXT', 'GLOVIS CHORUS', 'VEHICLES CARRIER', 199.99, 'Gulf Agency Company (Brisbane)', '/Date(1642680000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642680000000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Point Cartwright Anchorage', 'PLAN', 'Port Kembla', 'Pyeongtaek ', '77A', 630944, 705], [132505, 334744, 'EXT', 'NSU CHALLENGER', 'BULK CARRIER', 299.95, 'Gulf Agency Company (Gladstone)', '/Date(1642680000000+1000)/', '/Date(1642683600000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Fairway Buoy Anchorage', 'PLAN', 'Nagoya', 'Oita', None, 633706, 705], [132727, 335219, 'EXT', 'RTM DIAS', 'BULK CARRIER', 234.87, 'Wilhelmsen Ships Service (Weipa)', '/Date(1642680900000+1000)/', '/Date(1642680900000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Weipa Anchorage', 'PLAN', 'Gladstone', 'China', None, 633623, 705], [132859, 335500, 'ARR', 'FOURCROY', 'LANDING CRAFT', 49.8, 'Sea Swift Pty Ltd', '/Date(1642685400000+1000)/', '/Date(1642686900000+1000)/', 'SEA', 'Horn Island Barge Ramp', 'CONF', 'Saibai Island', 'Weipa', None, 633180, 725]], 'IsCustomMetaData': False, 'MetaData': {'__type': 'DataTableMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Columns': [{'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'HAlignment': 'haright', 'Name': 'VOYAGE_ID', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Voyage Id', 'Visible': False, 'Width': '50px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'HAlignment': 'haright', 'Name': 'ID', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Id', 'Visible': False, 'Width': '20px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'Name': 'JOB_TYPE_CODE', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Job Type', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '71px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '"link": {"title":"Ship Info", "type":"dashboard", "target":"_popup", "code":"standard.vesselinfo", "params":[{"name":"VID","value":"[%VESSEL_ID%]"}]}', 'Name': 'VESSEL_NAME', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Ship', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '94px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'Name': 'MSQ_SHIP_TYPE', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Ship Type', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '115px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'HAlignment': 'haright', 'Name': 'LOA', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'LOA', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '95px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'Name': 'AGENCY_NAME', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Agency', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '287px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'Name': 'START_TIME', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Start Time', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '91px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'Name': 'END_TIME', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'End Time', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '91px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'Name': 'FROM_LOCATION_NAME', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'From Location', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '139px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'Name': 'TO_LOCATION_NAME', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'To Location', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '139px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'Name': 'STATUS_TYPE_CODE', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Status', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '83px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'Name': 'LASTPORT_NAME', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Last Port', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '114px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'Name': 'NEXTPORT_NAME', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Next Port', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '114px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'Name': 'VOYAGE_NUMBER', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Sortable': True, 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Voyage #', 'Visible': True, 'Width': '45px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'HAlignment': 'haright', 'Name': 'VESSEL_ID', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Vessel Id', 'Visible': False, 'Width': '64px'}, {'__type': 'ColumnMetaDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Format': '', 'HAlignment': 'haright', 'Name': 'STATUS_TYPE', 'SortIndex': -1, 'SortOrder': '', 'Template': '', 'Title': 'Status Type', 'Visible': False, 'Width': '64px'}], 'Script': 'var data = this.getData();\nvar $row = this.get$Row();\nvar $jobtype = this.get$Cell(\'JOB_TYPE\');\n\nvar $startTime = this.get$Cell(\'START_TIME\');\nvar $endTime = this.get$Cell(\'END_TIME\');\n\nif (data.JOB_TYPE == "Arrival")\n{\n  $jobtype.css(\'color\', \'green\');\n}\nif (data.JOB_TYPE == "Departure")\n{\n  $jobtype.css(\'color\', \'blue\');\n}\nif (data.JOB_TYPE == "Shift")\n{\n  $jobtype.css(\'color\', \'#8B7500\');\n}\nif (data.JOB_TYPE == "External")\n{\n  $jobtype.css(\'color\', \'grey\');\n}\n\nif (data.STATUS_TYPE >= 735 &&data.STATUS_TYPE < 750 )\n{\n    $startTime.css(\'font-weight\', \'bold\');\n    $endTime.css(\'font-weight\', \'bold\');\n    $startTime.css(\'font-style\', \'italic\');\n    $endTime.css(\'font-style\', \'italic\');\n}\n\n', 'TemplateRow': '', 'TemplateTable': '', 'Version': 0}, 'Name': 'DATA'}]}}
```

I've tried using `pd.json_normalize` with and without `record_path`. Specifying `record_path` draws an error where column name can't be found.

```
print(pd.json_normalize(my_dict))
```

Output:

```
                    d.__type d.BuildVersion  d.ReportCode                                           d.Tables
0  DataSetDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO    7.0.0.12590  MSQ-WEB-0001  [{'__type': 'DataTableDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Bu...

print(pd.json_normalize(my_dict, record_path=['Data']))
```

Error:

```
File "/Users/kevin_o'connell/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py", line 243, in _pull_field
result = result[spec]

KeyError: 'Data'
```

I've also tried the following but as the print out shows, I'm not returning the tabular information associated with `Data`.

```
print(pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v).T for k, v in my_dict.items()}, axis=0))

                                                                0
d __type                                DataSetDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO
  BuildVersion                                        7.0.0.12590
  ReportCode                                         MSQ-WEB-0001
  Tables        {'__type': 'DataTableDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO', 'Bui...
```

Returning the desired info as an object, not a pandas df:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(my_dict['d'], 'Tables')

df = pd.DataFrame(df['Data'].T)
```

Out:

```
                                                Data
0  [[132393, 334520, EXT, CESI BEIHAI, LIQUEFIED ...
```

list meta as a parameter:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(my_dict['d'], record_path = 'Tables', meta = ['Data'], errors = 'ignore')

    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Conflicting metadata name Data, need distinguishing prefix
```

Comment: The dictionary you posted is incomplete. Please post an example of data that is correct (if incomplete) or a link to a complete example if it's too large to post.

Comment: What part of the data are you expecting to end up in the dataframe and how? It seems like the `'Data'` key has tabular data, but there's no information on column names or anything else - do you just want that data in a dataframe with numbered columns?

Comment: Yep it's too long, I'll attach a link. Getting `Data` into a tabular df would be a start. Even if columns headers aren't available. In that case, shouldn't `pd.json_normalize(my_dict, record_path=['Data'])` work?

Comment: Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65308566/pandas-json-normalize-returns-keyerror

Comment: Thanks, that allows me to return `Data` as an object, I'm just trying to get it into a pandas df.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`record_path` is the **path** to the record, so you should specify the full path

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['d', 'Tables', 'Data'])
```

If you want to do without `record_path`, the value type of `Data` is list of list. You can use `pd.DataFrame` directly

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data['d']['Tables'][0]['Data'])
```

```
print(df)

        0       1    2                   3                 4       5   ...    11                 12           13       14      15   16
0   132378  334489  EXT              NANA Z      BULK CARRIER  229.20  ...  PLAN  Keelung (Chilung)    Kwangyang     None  633086  705
1   132112  333984  DEP       KRITI WARRIOR      BULK CARRIER  234.98  ...  CONF              Amrun        Amrun     2201  632395  725
2   132232  334208  EXT  BLUE GRASS MARINER            TANKER  183.06  ...  PLAN          Gladstone    Singapore     None  633566  705
3   132654  335076  EXT     SERIFOS WARRIOR      BULK CARRIER  234.98  ...  PLAN              Amrun        Amrun     2201  632055  705
4   132030  333847  ARR            MH GREEN    CONTAINER SHIP  199.98  ...  SCHD            Yantian   Botany Bay  11S/11N  633005  710
..     ...     ...  ...                 ...               ...     ...  ...   ...                ...          ...      ...     ...  ...
71  132456  334647  EXT    MISSY ENTERPRISE     GENERAL CARGO  181.16  ...  PLAN          Singapore        Japan        2  631532  705
72  132389  335619  EXT       GLOVIS CHORUS  VEHICLES CARRIER  199.99  ...  PLAN        Port Kembla  Pyeongtaek       77A  630944  705
73  132505  334744  EXT      NSU CHALLENGER      BULK CARRIER  299.95  ...  PLAN             Nagoya         Oita     None  633706  705
74  132727  335219  EXT            RTM DIAS      BULK CARRIER  234.87  ...  PLAN          Gladstone        China     None  633623  705
75  132859  335500  ARR            FOURCROY     LANDING CRAFT   49.80  ...  CONF      Saibai Island        Weipa     None  633180  725

[76 rows x 17 columns]
```